# How to convert a file into an associative array? And use the first 3 characters as key

Tags: php, arrays, file, associative-array

I have a file like below, which I need to convert into an array:

```
ABCLine, Number, One
DEFNumber, Two, Line
GHIThree, Line, Number
```

I can get each line and turn it into a value of an array, but what I need to do is take the first 3 characters and turn that into a key and then the rest of the line into the value.

So my expected array would be:

```
Keys  |      Values
----------------------------
ABC   |  Line, Number, One
DEF   |  Number, Two, Line
GHI   |  Three, Line, Number
```

I honestly am not too sure where to begin, I've been looking all over and haven't been able to find a way to just take those first 3 characters and turn those into a key for the remainder of the line.

I started with some code, which looks like this:

```
<?php

  echo "Name<br/>";

  $file = "hw3.txt";
  $f1 = fopen($file, 'r');
  $array = array();


?>
```

Comment: Show us your current code and where you are stuck

Comment: Don't expect us to do all the work. Show us your code.

Comment: Sorry, I posted what little I have. I don't need the work done, I looked all over and can't find a way to take those characters and turn them into a key and take the rest and turn those into the values.  All I need is to be pointed in the right direction, I don't need the code written for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then walk through your array with [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and take the first 3 characters of each value and add it to the `$keys` array. After that you can remove the first 3 characters from the value.

At the end just [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) your `$keys` array with `$arr`, e.g.

```
<?php


    $arr = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $keys = [];
    array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k)use(&$keys){
       $keys[] = substr($v, 0, 3);
       $v = substr($v, 3);
    });     

    $arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [ABC] => Line, Number, One
    [DEF] => Number, Two, Line
    [GHI] => Three, Line, Number
)
```

Comment: Wow, did not think to just turn them both into arrays and combine them, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the first 3 characters with the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function, and use it as the key of your array, then store rest of the string as another array, for example:

```
$file = "hw3.txt";
$f1 = fopen($file, 'r');
$array = array();
while (($line = fgets($f1)) !== false) {
    $key = substr($line, 0, 3);
    $val = substr($line, 3);
    $array[$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: I tried it this way, but when I print_r the array, it just displays "Array ()"